# How can i use redis to manage message queue of my socket io

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, nestjs

I'm using socket.io, but i was wondering if i could use redis with socket.io so that when traffic increases i can just scale my redis server instead of server compute,
I tried looking for similar scenarios but the didnt find any solution to this
I would really appreciate someone pointing me to the resource or answering the question

Answer (score -1):

You can look into [bull queues](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) this will help you queue items and also remove duplication as well as in replacing existing items in the queue with the latest data

Comment: I didn't find a documentation mentioning how i can manage my socket message queues using bull or bullMQ @Aditya_Anand